# operator mismatch when assigning value to two dimensional array of type custom structure type

Tags: c++, sorting, operators, structure

Like what the title says. I'm getting errors from an operator mismatch.

Here's my structured datatype:

```
typedef struct{
int absent[SIZE];
string id[SIZE];
}sorttype;

sorttype temp_matrix[2][SIZE];
string empId[SIZE];
int absence[SIZE];
```

and here's the operation that I intend to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        temp_matrix[0][i] = empId[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    temp_matrix[1][i] = absence[i];
}
```

My editor says the mismatch is on the "temp_matrix[][] = array[]" part.

*As a side question:

The thing I'm doing here is actually to sort two separate arrays, empId[] and absence[] in ascending order based off absence[]'s values. But empId[] and absence[] are suppose to be paired together even though they're separate arrays. So I thought of placing their data in a two dimensional array. And that '>' operator also gives me an operator mismatch.

Here's what I thought of doing with the sorting:

```
do{ // sort absences array in ascending order
bool swap = false;
for (int count = 0; count < (SIZE - 1); count++){
     if (temp_matrix[1][count] > temp_matrix[1][count + 1]){
        temp1 = temp_matrix[1][count];
        temp2 = temp_matrix[0][count];
        temp_matrix[1][count] = temp_matrix[1][count + 1];
        temp_matrix[0][count] = temp_matrix[0][count + 1];
        temp_matrix[1][count + 1] = temp1;
        temp_matrix[0][count] = temp2;
        swap = true;
     }
}
} while (swap);
```

Comment: Are absent and id supposed to be arrays?

Comment: Yes, they are I guess I forgot to place the declarations in this question.

Comment: `temp_matrix[][]` expression has type `sorttype` while `empId[]` has type `string` and `absence[]` type `int`.